# how to write unit test code for custom collectionView cell in xcode8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I am new to write unit test codes. Can any one tell me how to write unit test code for custom collectionView cell. This is  the code i tried, it shows cell is nil.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewCellTests : XCTestCase
 {
        UICollectionView *testCollectionView;
        CollectionViewCell *customCell;

 }
@end

@implementation CollectionViewCellTests

 - (void)setUp {
     [super setUp];
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        //[testCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
       // [testCollectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 }

- (void)tearDown {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testCustomCollectionViewCell {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        customCell =  (CollectionViewCell *)[testCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        XCTAssertNotNil(customCell, @"No Custom Cell Available");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a Cell is quite suitable for testing as per unit tests,
I recommend to use a XCUItest instead. You would then basically assert that the cell represents the actual data and that all the parts are visible as expected.

In the setup portion you would populate the data and then the actual test would assert that the view is correctly presented.

Comment: Make sure that you have set your tableview to have some data, this needs to be done in your setup portion. So you would have to expose your class data container so that you can add some data to it from your uitest. You can set breakpoints at your tableView:numberOfRowsInSection is being called and you return an correct amount, typically yourData.count

Comment: I actually recommend you watch some short video on XCUITests, you can quickly record some user actions, and refine your test from there.